# Jquery UI Autocomplete and Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, autocomplete

I have a old page that uses Jquery validation

```
<script src="global/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="global/scripts/accordion.js"></script>
<script src="global/scripts/jquery.hint.js"></script>
<script src="global/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

also uses a datepicker. I introduced jquery autocomplete functionally to the page and that stopped the date picker icon from being displayed and even the validation is not happening for any field.

The following is the version that i use for jquery.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
< script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css>
```

If i remove these imports and the

```
$("#someID").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "servlet/Suggest?jquerysearch="+$("#someID").val(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                          
                        response(data)
                    }                       
               }); 
            },  
            select: function(event, ui ) {
                setSearchBySubmitJQ(ui.item.value);             
            }
        });
```

If i introduce any of these autocomplete code. the existing validation and date picker is gone. Does anyone know if there is a version mismatch. When i try removing jquery-1.7.2.min.js the validation and date pick does not appear at all.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle showing your problem? I'm not seeing where you're loading the validation plugin. Also, 1.7.2 is a _very_ old version of jQuery. Please consider updating the version you're using.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is that you have a compatibility mismatch. You are introducing jquery-ui-1.10.3  and the older version of jquery. There must be some dependencies in 1.10 that are not yet in 1.7. What I would do is, I would try to introduce a more up to date version of jquery. On the bottom of **[jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/)** it is suggested to use jquery 1.9.1

Comment: you were rite. I had problems with my jquery version. I downloaded only autocomplete from jquery UI and included in the jsp. it started working from then. Thank you for helping me with right direction.